# How to construct a network by subsetting based on time period

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am kind of new to everything here. I tried to put more effort to make my code readable.  I am writing the code for running a function for multiple files. I have over 100 files and each file contains edgelist with time(session)as follows:

```
Header: Time Sender Receiver

      1    1       2
      1    1       3
      2    2       1
      2    2       1
      3    1       2
      3    1       2
```

The purpose of the function is to extract sub-networks from each file based on 'Time'. Since there are 3 different time periods, each file will have 3 sub-networks. The following is the code that I wrote:

```
SubsetNetwork <-function (file) {
  df = read.csv(file)
  uniq <-unique(unlist(df$Time))
  edgelist=list()
  g=list()
  for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
    g <- lapply(split(df, df$Time), function(x) {
      graph.edgelist(as.matrix(x[c("Sender","Receiver")]), directed = T)
    })
    edgelist[[i]]=get.edgelist(g[[i]])

    filename=paste(fname, i, ".csv")
    write.csv(edgelist[[i]], filename)
  }
}
```

This code will run the above the function.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
for (i in 1:length(temp)){      
  file <-temp[i]              
  SubsetNetwork (file)
}
```

- Input file =626234T.csv
- Output files = 626234T1.csv, 626234T2.csv, 626234T3.csv.

I kept getting the error (`Error in g[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`). If I ran a code one by one, it seemed working. However, if I fed multiple files, it generated outputs for several files and stopped working. I couldn't figure out what caused the problem.

Comment: Please put more effort into making code readable (and reproducible). Just posting a screen-scrape without a library call for non-base functions is not sufficient effort. You should also post output from `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing, but does this help: `lapply(split(df, df$Time), function(x) graph.edgelist(as.matrix(x[c("Sender", "Receiver")]), directed = T))`? (`df` is the dataframe in the end (Time Sender etc)). The output is a list of 3 `IGRAPH D--- 3 2 --`-like elements.

Comment: sorry that my code was not readable. I am not used to write a code. I try to learn by myself. @alexis_laz Thank you. I guess  your code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working fine for one file, the error you're getting indicates that it isn't a problem with your code. You should only be getting `g[[i]]` is out of bounds if the number of unique time points is < 1.

I suspect that what's happening is there is a malformed or corrupted file lacking a "Time" header that is being picked up by `temp <- list.files(*.csv)`.

Since you're not used to writing code, I'll go through, critique and fix some things for you:

```
SubsetNetwork <-function (file) {
  df = read.csv(file)
  uniq <-unique(unlist(df$Time))
```

Columns of `data.frames` are just vectors, so you don't need the `unlist` here. Instead:

```
  uniq <-unique(df$Time)
```

Is sufficient.

```
  edgelist=list()
  g=list()
  for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
    g <- lapply(split(df, df$Time), function(x) {
      graph.edgelist(as.matrix(x[c("Sender","Receiver")]), directed = T)
    })
    edgelist[[i]]=get.edgelist(g[[i]])

    filename=paste(fname, i, ".csv")
    write.csv(edgelist[[i]], filename)
  }
}
```

You may not actually need the `for` loop here. `lapply` of the `split` data frame will return the entire list, so can be moved outside the loop. If `get.edgelist` is vectorized, this can also be moved outside of the loop. Since I don't actually know I'll assume it isn't just to be safe:

```
  g <- lapply(split(df, df$Time), function(x) {
    graph.edgelist(as.matrix(x[c("Sender","Receiver")]), directed = T)
  })
  edgelist <- lapply(g, get.edgelist)

  for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
    filename=paste(fname, i, ".csv")
    write.csv(edgelist[[i]], filename)
  }
}
```

Now, you also don't need `uniq` because the number of `unique` time points is simply the length of both `g` and your `edgelist`.

When `filename=paste(fname, i, ".csv")`, the `paste` function will insert spaces between each argument (ie `fname 1 .csv` instead of `fname1.csv`.  You can either specify `sep=""` to change the behaviour of `paste` or use `paste0` as shorthand.

Bringing that all back together:

```
SubsetNetwork <-function (file) {
  df = read.csv(file)
  g <- lapply(split(df, df$Time), function(x) {
    graph.edgelist(as.matrix(x[c("Sender","Receiver")]), directed = T)
  })
  edgelist <- lapply(g, get.edgelist)

  for (i in 1:length(g)){
    filename=paste0(fname, i, ".csv")
    write.csv(edgelist[[i]], filename)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Since I try to learn R by myself, I was using pieces of codes from other people's (even I was not sure what they really did). Anyway thanks to you, I learned a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! I noticed a lot of advance concepts for someone just learning, so i thought i'd help out a little :)